# django using MEDIA URL in a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

i'm trying to access files that were uploaded by users.

i have the following settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'project/media/') 

MEDIA_URL = '/project/media/'
```

and the file are:

```
path = models.FileField(upload_to="myApp")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="myApp/logos", null=True, blank=True)
```

in the template i try to acces it in the following way:

```
{{MEDIA_URL}}{{file.path}}
```

but it doesn't work..

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`file.path` returns an object representing the file, what you want is `file.path.url` which takes care of adding the `MEDIA_URL`.

Comment: i change it to {{file.path.url}} and it gives me the correct path to the file 
(relative to the project directory) but i still can't download/view the files..

Comment: @brad you need to serve the `MEDIA_ROOT` with a HTTP server, see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) to learn how to do it in development.

Comment: @brad yes it is `file.path.url` not `file.url` I made a mistake

Comment: it still doesn't work.. i really can't understand what i'm doing wrong.. it downloads the file but the content of it is the html of the current page

Comment: i needed to add the following: url(r'^project/media(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),    now it's working