# How to modify a string of a field in a queryset in Django, to display it in a templatetag

Tags: django

I have the next queryset:

```
fotosinfo=IndexHasFotografia.objects.filter(index_idindex=infoindex,ubicacion_fotografiaindex=1).values('fotografia_idfotografia__pk','fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia','fotografia_idfotografia__nombre_fotografia')
```

Where `fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia` stores an image URL, but the stored route is something like this `./image.jpg` and it must be `/files/image.jpg`. In template I can add `/files` before the template tag, but I can't remove the dot before the slash. I can't change the way that images are stored, because I have stored a lot of images. I displayed other images using json, and that was easier, but now I must use template tags. So, how can I remove that dot to show the image URL in a template tag?

---

I have tried to use slice filter, as the answer to this question: [Remove first character from string Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005648/remove-first-character-from-string-django-template) but now the string dissapeard.

My html with a template tag inside, looks like this:

```
<img src="{{ fotosslide.first.fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia.name|slice:'1:' }}">
```

Comment: Why not search your db and find all the instances starting with `./` and replace that for `/files/`?

Comment: Aren't you just trying to add a static/media file URL? is `/files/` your `MEDIA_URL`/`STATIC_URL`?

Comment: @allcaps That will be a good solution :D And I have found the way to do it, it was my bad on the slice filter.

Comment: @vmonteco /files/ is my media URL, I now there's a way to append MEDIA_URL variable in a template, but, that works on deploy or only on development?

Comment: DEV, TST, ACC, PRD, all will have `/files/` as media url but Django only serves this dir with de dev server (right config and DEBUG=True). In other situations you need to configure your server to serve `/files/` for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was only reloading the code of the page, and not the actual page to see its code, that was why the html wasn't updated. It works in the way I posted it, the dot was removed, and later I just appended `files`, this is how it looks like:

```
<img src='/files{{ fotosslide.0.fotografia_idfotografia__ruta_fotografia|slice:"1:"}}'>
```

I don't know yet if the image has been showed, because it is part of a slide and javascript is not working, I have to check that. But the URL is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to handle some media files.

Django doesn't serve these files by default (in production, that's a HTTP server like Nginx or Apache that serves your files). But you can enable it in a developpment environment by adding this to your root `urls.py` file :

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Don't forget to import `settings` (in `django.conf`) and `static` (in `django.conf.urls.static`)

[more here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

You can use your files' urls in your templates as regular static/media files urls, these files should be served by your django development server (if `DEBUG` is `True`).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

then just use the file's `path.url` attribute in your template as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012280/3156085).